# Html Radio button selection

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

Following is my code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#es").hide();
    $("#n").hide();
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
        if (this.value === "Yes")
            $("#es").show();
        else if (this.value === "No")
            $("#n").show();
    });
});
```

There are 2 radio buttons for yes and no.After selecting yes if select no only no option should be selected but here both buttons are getting selecte.How can i rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

give same name both of radio button like this

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="no">No
```

Answer (score 8):

Just provide both of them the same name. You don't need javascript to do that.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="group" id="es" value="Yes"/>Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="group" id="n" value="No"/>No</label>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vNyS6/)**

Comment: Are you saying something on the web can be done *without* jQuery?

Comment: this was sarcasm; even when not needed, jQuery is everywhere :/

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer.Actually i saw sonusindhu's answer first and tried that it was working after that ly i saw yours.so i've chosen that.no other reasons

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the radio buttons. 
 Give same names to the radio buttons to do so.